# Laravel 5.4 remove public from url :Side effects

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have successfully removed 'public' from my Laravel project URL.

Now when I include any asset using helper function asset() I have to include public at all places like below.

asset('public/images/a.img')

When I try dumping helper function basepath() and publicpath(), correct values are displayed. How can I avoid writing public all the times in all calls to asset. Is there anyway asset function uses publicpath() instead of basepath().

Comment: There should not be a `public` in your url to begin with. My guess is that your doc root points to the `/app` dir instead of the `/app/public/` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your Web Directory on your Web Server to point to

```
/yourproject/public
```

it seems like your pointing now to

```
/yourproject/
```

Comment: I have set public_html as my webdirectory and within it I have many projects. Each project has its own .htaccess files and it own directory.